# What are the fundamentals of a tennis forehand?

Tags: tennis, technique

What should one consider when making a forehand stroke in tennis, and what should you look to avoid?

Answer (score 3):

## What to do

1. Use a proper grip. People have different tastes, but the most common one these days is called [the semi-western grip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grip_(tennis)#The_Semi-Western_Forehand_Grip_(Bevel_#4)).
2. Make a unit turn (take back) with the help of the non-hitting hand; this will coil your upper body well.
3. Take a good "power position" with the racket head pointing up, while stretching the non-hitting hand to the side at the height of the shoulder. The extended non-hitting hand helps you measure the distance from the ball.
4. Create a nice and relaxed racket lag by flipping the racket. Now the grip end is leading the racket head and you swing the racket forward.
5. When your hitting arm reaches the contact point, which is a little ahead of your body, the racket head accelerates and overtakes the grip end by the centrifugal force to hit the ball.
6. Still using the centrifugal force, direct the racket head by the pronation of the forearm to make so-called "wiper action" just about the time you hit the ball.
7. Keep your head pointing to the contact point while you finish the swing by a nice follow-through.

## Not to do

1. Use a wrong grip. The continental grip is now considered outdated because it is not suitable to create good topspin.
2. Non-hitting arm just dangling down while at the power position (take back). You may not able to coil your upper body well. The balance of the body may not be good. You may struggle to measure the distance of a ball.
3. Too much take back. Even at the power position, the racket should still be on the side of your hitting arm. Too much take back takes your time without actually accelerating the racket head speed.
4. Force the racket lag. It has to be achieved in a nice and effortless way. Otherwise, you might hurt your elbow.
5. Holding the grip tightly when swinging and hitting a ball. You need to relax the grip and the wrist to accelerate the racket head speed by the centrifugal force.
6. Force the wiper action by muscular strength. This might hurt your elbow.

Answer (score 1):

According to optimumtennis.net, you should make sure you have proper positioning. Some other tips are to avoid a closed racket, holding your racket with a closed grip upon contact. You should also make sure that your swing angle is correct, from low to high. The other tips for a forehand stroke is to follow through, and transfer your weight.

Answer (score 0):

**What to do:**

- Stand next to the ball
- Make sure you are in the right grip
- Make sure you have both hands on the racket (right hand at the bottom if right-handed) then turn, let your let hand go and swing
- Make sure you follow through
- Get back in your ready positio before it bounces on the other side

**Not to do:**

- Stand in front of the ball
- Hit with both hands
- Not follow through
- Not get back in the ready position afterwards